# How to pass username and password in the localhost url to connect with the memcached in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memcached, spymemcached, libmemcached

Hi, I want to pass the username and password to connect to localhost where I have deployed  memcached.

Here is my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient;

public class MemCaheConnection {

    public void ConnectMemCaheConnection() throws IOException{

        MemcachedClient c = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 11211));
        c.flush();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

without explicit use of http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLAuthProtocol there is no need for username+password, did you check the service is running on port 11211?